# Ajax call showing error cant debug

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

this is how the javascript looks like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loginButton').click(function () {
        //this.disabled = true;
        debugger;
        var data = {
            "userid": $("#username").val(),
            "password": $("#password").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/LoginPost",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Success) {
                    $.get("@Url.Action("Search", "Home")", function (data) {
                        $('.container').html(data);
                    });
                }
                else
                    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";
            },
            error: function () {
                 alert('Login Fail!!!');
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

I am getting the alert('Login fail') also debugger not getting hit.
I am using jquery 1.9.1 and have included unobstrusive

my controller is this as you can i am passing string values not object values
to the controller so stringify is justified here

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoginPost(string userid, string password)
{
    using (someentities wk = new someentities())
    {
        var LoginUser = wk.tblUsers.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(userid)&&a.Password.Equals(password)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (LoginUser != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userid,false);
            Session["Username"] = LoginUser.Username;
            Session["Password"] = LoginUser.Password;
            Session["Name"] = LoginUser.Name;
            return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Login"] = "Please Enter Correct Login Details";
            return Json(new { Success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
}
```

when page is loading these error are shown

> $(..) live is not a valid function in
>   (anonymous function) @ jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:115
>   (anonymous function) @ jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:163

Comment: So what do you see in the network panel?

Comment: in `$.ajax`, `ERROR` is triggered when the server returns an `error`, so you will want to try `error:function(obj){console.log(obj);` to see what error the server is returning.

Comment: As @epascarello said, we're not going to be able to give you much help without knowing if it's a server-side error, or a client-side error, though given the fact that it's hitting the error callback rather than the success, it seems like it's much more likely that it's a server-side error.

Comment: `error: function () { console.log(arguments); }`

Comment: In my console on page loading these errors are shown $() live is not a function

Comment: keep a breakpoint in your action method and check if its hitting

Comment: You are using a version of `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` that is not compatible with `jquery 1.9.1` (`.live()` was deprecated in v1.7 and removed in v1.9). But why in the world are you using that script if you using jquery.ajax to submit your form. Side note: You can just use `data: data.` and remove `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: i will try that i really appreciate your answer

Comment: action is not getting a hit i did that Karthik M R

Answer (score 0):

take a look to the success function

```
           success: function (response) {
                if (response.Success) {
                    $.get("@Url.Action("Search", "Home")", function (data) {
                        $('.container').html(data);
                    });
                }
                else
                    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";
            }
```

you are using multiple **"**, combine it with the single one **'**, this is a syntax error, try to check the code on an editor such as Atom, to avoid this kind of errors

Answer (score 0):

`Stringify` converts an `object` to a `string`. Have you tried passing `data` an `object` instead of a `string`? Try replacing `JSON.stringify(data),` with `data`?